# What is the difference between having multiple namespace and multiple cluster in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am a beginner and learning about Kubernetes.

As per my understanding, namespace is a virtual cluster backed by the same physical cluster.

In which usecases do we go for separate physical Kubernetes cluster?

What are the main resources that can be saved by opting for namespace instead of physical Kubernetes cluster? (Kubernetes objects present in one namespace of the physical cluster can be shared by all other namespaces, like the ones in kube-system? And are the nodes in the physical Kubernetes cluster shared by all the namespaces but it is not possible to share nodes between multiple physical Kubernetes clusters?)

Comment: first of all there is a service cost difference

Comment: it is analogous to having virtual servers vs dedicated servers, cost is a major option and efficiency so if dont want to raise costs and you dont mind efficiency then virtual hosting is fine, else dedicated hosting IMO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A namespace isn't a "virtual cluster" in any meaningful way; it's just a way to group together resources.  For instance, these Services are different because they're in different namespaces:

```sh
kubectl describe service --namespace n1 foo
kubectl describe service --namespace n2 foo
```

But a service in `n1` can make a call to `foo.n2.svc.cluster.local` without doing any special setup.

A namespace is a natural boundary for Kubernetes RBAC settings.  If one object directly references another (*e.g.*, a pod mounts a persistent volume claim or gets environment variables from a config map) they generally must be in the same namespace.

In an actual cluster, the nodes are shared.  A given node can run any pod from any namespace (unless that's specifically configured at the pod level); `kubectl describe node` will show this.  If a pod makes very heavy use of some resource (CPU, memory, disk I/O) this can impact other pods running on the same node.  That completely ignores namespace boundaries.

You want different clusters when you want things to actually be separated: when a service in one environment shouldn't be able to call a service in a different environment, when cluster-level resources like NodePort services need to be separated, if you have different policies around things like PersistentVolume allocation.

Sharing a cluster means that you need fewer copies of some cluster-global processes (the Kubernetes core, service meshes like Istio) and you can share nodes.  That could result in better utilization of large nodes.

You might, for example, separate your test and production environments into separate clusters.  These would have different external-DNS settings, separate ingress controllers, and separate node pools.  You couldn't accidentally send requests into the test environment from outside, and a load test on the test environment wouldn't impact the production environment.

Comment: So the difference between namespaces in a cluster and actual physical cluster is that the nodes are shared between namespaces but not in case of physical cluster, right? Otherwise, we might as well go for a separate Kubernetes cluster because we have the resource capacity. So it is also probably meaningless to assign dedicated node to particular namespace because we might as well setup a physical cluster, the only caveat being that we need to duplicate kubernetes' internal objects again in each physical cluster (like the ones in the kube-system namespace) which is not required for namespaces.

Comment: Secondly, so a Test environment and Production environment should NOT be set up as namespaces within the same physical cluster because services in one namespace can call other services present in other namespaces within the same physical cluster? So may be if there are multiple teams in a company/enterprise using the Test environment then each team can have a separate namespace so that they can reuse the kubernetes’ internal objects present in kube-system namespace and also make use of common enterprise wide libraries by placing them in kube-public namespace

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't let you assign nodes to namespaces.  Persistent volumes and NodePort services are similarly cluster-global.

Comment: Scripting or otherwise automating the initial cluster setup is a good idea and that would make it possible to have multiple similarly-configured clusters.  Sharing a test cluster with a namespace per team is reasonable, but you probably don't want to share your test and prod environments.

Answer (score 2):

Generally a separate physical cluster is necessary

1. To meet compliance and security standards such as [PCI DSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard), [HIPPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act) etc.
2. To provide dedicated physical resources to critical workloads.
3. To separate different environments such as DEV, TEST, PROD

A multi tenant cluster shared by many tenants using their own namespace is useful for saving cost. Namespace separation is logical where the resources of all namespaces still reside in same ETCD storage but with different keys. This is not a problem in separate dedicated physical cluster because in that case the cluster will have separate ETCD as well.

Access to resources across namespaces is controlled by RBAC via kubernetes API Server. But you can access everything from all namespaces if you get access to ETCD directly bypassing the API Server.

You need to put lot of best practices and protection in a multi tenant cluster so that tenants from different namespaces do not step on each other toes. This not that much necessary in a separate dedicated physical cluster.